# OpenWrt in Microsoft Azure or Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, hyper-v, openwrt, nic

**Goal:** I would like to run OpenWrt in a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine.

**Problem:** From researching it appears that Azure and Hyper-V have the same issue where the **Virtual NIC are not detected**.

**Supposed Solution:** Supposedly the solution is to patch OpenWrt Source with Tulip. (Open Wrt Forum on subject: https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/5770)

**Problem:** I can't seem to find a working patch to patch openWrt to support tulip.

**Question:** Has anyone successfully used OpenWrt in an Azure virtual machine or in Hyper-V? If so where can I get the patch or is there another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this tutorial http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build

Run "make menuconfig" and navigate to kernel packages, network devices, and select tulip family. (This will allow Hyper-V Legacy adapters to be recognized and configured within OpenWrt)

Then run "make", extract *combined*.gz, convert extracted file to vhd using qemu-img http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_converting.html

Then create a vim and use the .vhd as the virtual hard disk

Answer (score 1):

The ticket you referenced was for the BackFire release in 2010. If you use that image then it should work for you.

git://git.openwrt.org/10.03/openwrt.git - BackFire

Comment: That is a good point. I downloaded that source and checked the devices.mk file but it doesn't have tulip support, so I wonder if it ever made it to a release. Just in case I tested it and it doesn't work.